# Microsoft Graph API: List applications for signed-in user

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

While the Microsoft Graph API seems to be very complete feature wise, it seems like I am stuck at a fairly easy request. For a small web application I want to list apps that are registered in Azure. What a want to do with them is a little bit out of scope, but in the end I want to show the user some important applications (which we flag in some way - using tags or something like that) that the user has access to.

Now, using the /applications resource in the beta endpoint of the Graph API I can retrieve a list of applications. Now, the application does not need admin consent. When requesting the apps, it retrieves all registered apps, which is a bit odd I think. Why would it return all apps and not just the ones that are assigned to me?

But okay, lets move on. Now I have the list of apps (or the metadata of it). How can I determine if the signed-in user has access to this application (or it doesn't require assignment). Am I missing something or is this nowhere to be found?

Comment: Wich is the url that you are using? https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications ?

Comment: @S-Wing, correct. It returns all registered applications, even if I use a simple account that doesn't have any permissions. And again, the app doesn't require user consent.

Comment: As you said in your post it isn't very usefull for your purpouse but in fact (if I understand correctly ) it's the correct behaviour; with that url you aren't asking for the application of the signed-in user ( there isn't the access to the beta/me resource that rapresents the logged user ), but all the registered application. The part that isn't clear for me is how the API recognize that your user has the permission to do that request ( you said that  the app doesn't require user consent ).

Comment: @S-Wing, it does require user consent, but not admin consent. For me it feels weird that logged in users can list all registered apps, even if they don't own them.

But like I said, I get the entire list, fine with me too, but there is no way to get the actual application permissions for the application?

Comment: I re-read the documentation but I don't find anything to get the behaviour  that you require (probably for security reasons). For your last question (get the actual user permissions for the application ), in fact you already know the permission (only for the application you are authenticated) because you have to specify them in the content of the authentication token request ( in the scopes field ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [appRoleAssignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/approleassignment-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) with the neccessary parameters to retrieve all apps a user has access to. Turned out to be quite simple. Beta only, but stable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use query parameters to customize responses. Please check the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/graph/query-parameters